# arcgis geopackage - Coordinate System

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I've just been saving (via /save as) a GeoPackage in QGIS (2.18.11) - which worked pretty fine. The output layer CRS information is correctly identified as WGS84 including EPSG code (4326).

The same GeoPackage in ArcGIS 10.4 (and 10.5) is identified as a WGS84 but EPSG information is missing - thus the feature class properties are set to "Custom" by ArcGIS. As a consequence, the relevant information for ArcGIS' semi-automatic transformation is missing, which results in serious troubles with projection on the fly for any kind of non WGS84-based projection. As far as I could figure out the CRS settings of the GeoPackage can't be changed within ArcGIS.

Is there

- a way to verify the CRS-settings of the GeoPackage (with an external tool)?
- a way to edit that settings with any kind of tool?
- or a known workaround for ArcGIS?

Comment: In GeoPackage the table "gpkg_contents" is listing all the tables and their srs_id. Or you can read that info from table "gpkg_geometry_columns". Finally run `SELECT * FROM "gpkg_spatial_ref_sys" WHERE srs_id=xxxx`. If projection is not recognized correctly there must be a bug either in GGIS/GDAL or in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what systems you're running and software you have installed, you can check the meta data using `ogrinfo` from the command line (if on windows I believe you'll likely need to install the OSGEO4W packages, which you may already have from your QGIS install).

Arc often doesn't read perfectly fine CRS data made outside of Arc, even when it's WGS84, but you can fix this by simply using the define projection tool. It will just redefine the CRS of the layer.

Comment: thx for the information. ogrinfo returns <br> GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]] <br> which seems quite ok ... and thus should be ok for ArcGIS as well

Comment: ... and ArcGIS' define projection tool returns an error - "cannot alter the spatial reference of xxxxx", seems that the tool doesn't change geopackages' properties

Comment: If the subtle difference is still causing problems you could try to use ogr2ogr (again on the command line) using the -update and -a_src flags to redefine the projection to what makes Arc happy. I've previously pulled the WKT of the CRS from files that Arc reads happily (using ogrinfo again) or maybe here (http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84/esriwkt/).