# Changing srs-definition string in geopackage with ogr2ogr

Tags: coordinate-system, ogr2ogr, wgs84, geopackage

When creating a geopackage with ogr2ogr in WGS84 (EPSG:4326), the srs-definition string cannot be interpreted correctly when loading the data into ArcGIS. ArcGIS does not project the data corretly into my local SRS. I found, that ArcGIS expects another string for the SRS. So I am trying to set the new string with ogr2ogr and using the -a_srs -Option, as suggested here:

[arcgis-geopackage-coordinate-system](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251042/arcgis-geopackage-coordinate-system)

Here is my command:

```
ogr2ogr -f GPKG test2.gpkg -a_srs "GEOGCS[^"GCS_WGS_1984^",DATUM[^"D_WGS_1984^",SPHEROID[^"WGS_1984^",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM[^"Greenwich^",0],UNIT[^"Degree^",0.017453292519943295]]" test.gpkg
```

Inside the geopackage there is one line-layer, called "line_4326_gp".
What am I doing wrong?

I retreive the string with this command:

```
gdalsrsinfo -o wkt_esri epsg:4326
```

Comment: sounds like you need to raise a bug report with ESRI, GeoPackage is an internationally agreed standard that they claim to support

Comment: Your ogr2ogr command is not complete because it is missing the source of data but I guess you have dropped it while editing your question. You are on Linux, aren't you?

Comment: It is on a windows-machine. The source should be a layer named "main.linie_4326_gp" in test.gpkg. I tried to add the layername, but maybe I did not use the correct notation, because I always got the error message that the datasource is missing. How do I add the layer correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ArcGIS should not expect a SRID string that you are trying to attach. The OGC implementation guide http://www.geopackage.org/guidance/implementation_guide.html has a link to sample GeoPackage that implements the lowest level SRS support `the three built-in SRSs of EPSG::4326 (WGS-84), 0 (undefined geographic coordinate reference systems), and -1 (undefined Cartesian coordinate reference systems)`. That GeoPackage can be downloaded from https://portal.opengeospatial.org/files/?artifact_id=74984

The definition of that built-in EPSG:4326 is as follows:

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137, 298.257223563,]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]
```

I suggest to download the sample database and try how ArcGIS deals with it.

**EDIT**

You can update the EPSG:4326 definitions in the gpkg_spatial_ref_sys table to be the same that ESRI is using with these two ogrinfo commands:

```
ogrinfo -sql "update gpkg_spatial_ref_sys set definition='GEOGCS[\"GCS_WGS_1984\",DATUM[\"D_WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS_1984\",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0.0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.0174532925199433]]' where srs_id=4326" ArcGis_geopackage_4326.gpkg

ogrinfo -sql "update gpkg_spatial_ref_sys set srs_name='GCS_WGS_1984' where srs_id=4326" ArcGis_geopackage_4326.gpkg
```

Commands are tested on Windows, on Linux you may need to escape the double quotes in some other way.

Comment: I agree with you that sending a bug report is necessary I did it. But even if they fix it it will not solve my problem, because for older versions, like ArcGIS 10.4, they will certainly not fix it. So my problem is still unresolved: how can I assign the SRS string to the geo package?

Comment: Certainly you can assing your own SRS, every GeoPackage is an empty SQLite database initially. Could you create a new GeoPackage with ArcGIS and have a look at what is inserts into gpkg_spatial_ref_sys table for EPSG:4326? Even better if you could share such gpkg database.

Comment: A geopackage created with ArcGIS with a layer called "main.linie_4326_gp" can be downloaded here: https://drive.cnv.at/index.php/s/DPwEXYNBqRmA2Mr  May whole process is built upon ogr2ogr, so I am trying to avoid writing directly into the tables of the geopackage.

Comment: You can write directly into gpkg table with ogrinfo, see my edited answer.